# wxpython - Pubsub across files

Tags: python, wxpython

I am creating a GUI and I am using the MVC pattern for creating it. As doing so, I am using pubsub to manage the events between the backend and the front end.

How can I make pubsub go across files?

My files are behind the link [right here](http://milogert.com/gui_dnd.zip). (They are rather long files, my post would be huge otherwise.)

---

For instance:

On line 31 of **gui_btn_panel.py**, the program subscribes to the `ENABLE NEXT` mailbox (`pub.subscribe(self.next_step,"ENABLE NEXT")`).

Then, on line 232 of **gui_step_1.py**, the program publishes a message with the tag `ENABLE NEXT` (`pub.SendMessage("ENABLE NEXT")`).

---

I want to have `gui_btn_panel.py` catch that message, but it doesn't seem to.

If I have confused some, let me know! Hopefully someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

This is weird. I use the pubsub that is included in wxPython itself and have never had that issue, but I do it slightly differently: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/

Hopefully that will help you out. If not, you can try posting to the official wxPython mailing list. I know the author of pubsub is there and he answers questions there.

Comment: But you saw where my problem is right? So it is not my actual program that looks broken?

Comment: It looks right if you're following the directions on pubsub's website, yes. In fact, you seem to be doing it exactly the same.

Comment: FINALLY got it! I just needed to add `from pubsub import setuparg1` to __gui_main.py__. Everything is working perfectly, thanks to the direction Oliver provided.